# Add target="_blank" to all PDF-links

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I want to add a `target="blank"`-attribute to all links containing a PDF-file as `href`. To accomplish this, I want to do a `preg_replace` on `$content` including all the HTML with multiple PDf-links in it. I think something like this would work, but unfortunately it does not:

```
preg_replace('/((<a (?=.*\.pdf)(?!.*target="_blank").*?)>)/', '$2 target="_blank">', $content);
```

So for example the following should happen:

```
$content = '<html>
<a href="http://www.example.com/file.pdf" title="File">
<a href="/file2.pdf" title="File2">
<a href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" title="Image">
</html>';

preg_replace('/((<a (?=.*\.pdf)(?!.*target="_blank").*?)>)/', '$2 target="_blank">', $content);
    echo $content;
```

Should output:

```
<html>
<a href="http://www.example.com/file.pdf" title="File" target="_blank">
<a href="/file2.pdf" title="File2" target="_blank">
<a href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" title="Image">
</html>
```

Can you help me finding the right RegEx to do this?

If there is an easier way to accomplish the same, I would love to hear it.

Thank you!

Comment: When you're asking a question, please add an example of the input and expected output vs. actual output. That would make it easier to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and less error prone way is to use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`.
To add a `target` attribute to all anchors of which the href ends with `.pdf`, you can do:

```
<?php
$content = '<html>
<a href="http://www.example.com/file.pdf" title="File">
<a href="/file2.pdf" title="File2">
<a href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" title="Image">
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
/** @var DOMNodeList $anchors */
$anchors = $xpath->query('//a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 3) = ".pdf"][not(@target = "_blank")]');

/** @var DOMElement $anchor */
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    $anchor->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

- [DOMXPath documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- [DOMDocument documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! I did not know the `DOMDocument()`-class yet.